# How to return data to the popup window?

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I have an application that called a popup window. From this popup window is called the second window in which data is transmitted, such as an array of strings. In the second box, I can change the data in an array and return the modified data in the first popup window.

I've tried:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myFunction(arrayWithData);
```

but of course get an error, because the data send to the main app.

Tell me how to transfer data in the first popup window from a second, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a common bus, the simplest but ugly way is dispatching a custom event (which contains the data of the second popup window) from FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication, the first popup initially adds listener to that event and manipulate the data.